# Lua: How to take only certain functions from the library?

Tags: lua

I have library file service_functions.lua. There are hundreds of functions in it.

```
function foo1()
------------
end

function foo2()
------------
end
```

and so on

I don't want to load all functions.
Now I do:

```
dofile(script_path.."\\service_functions.lua")
```

and get all of them.
How to get only specific functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

but if, as you wrote in the question,  you need minimal memory load,
then maybe my version will come in handy
module:

```
local arg={...}

local function foo1() print("foo1")
end

local function foo2() print("foo2")
end

local function foo3() print("foo3")
end

local function foo4() print("foo4")
end
local M = {foo1=foo1, foo2=foo2, foo3=foo3, foo4=foo4} 

if not arg[1] then return M     -- all
elseif type(arg[1])=="string" then
    local x = {} 
    x[arg[1]] = M[arg[1]] 
    return x                   -- 1 function by name
elseif type(arg[1])=="table" then 
    local res = {}
    for k,v in pairs(arg[1]) do
       res[v] = M[v]
    end
    return  res                 -- some functions
end
```

and return only what is needed from "hundreds" of functions

```
-- only 1 function loaded

local x = loadfile("funk.lua")("foo1")
x.foo1()

-- only 2 functions loaded
local x = loadfile("funk.lua")( { "foo1", "foo2"} )

x.foo1()
x.foo2()

-- all functions loaded

local x = loadfile("funk.lua")()
x.foo1()
x.foo2()
x.foo3()
x.foo4()
```

Comment: Thank you! you have been of great help to me

Comment: How does that use minimal memory? All functions are compiled anyway. The code even creates 3 tables.

Comment: @lhf it's true, but the garbage collector will clean it up later

Comment: should I use collectgarbage() function in my code or it will be done automatically?

Comment: @IgorK. you can try, but not notice the difference, which means that the collector himself removed the unnecessary after using the second module ...the main thing is that loadfile will return not the whole module, but a part

Answer (score 2):

Write your library as follows:

```
local M={}

function M.foo1()
------------
end

function M.foo2()
------------
end

return M
```

Then load the library with

```
local lib=dofile(script_path.."\\service_functions.lua")
```

and extract the functions you need with

```
foo1 = lib.foo1
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, dear friend.

Answer (score 0):

Remove any function you don't want/need from service_functions.lua or wrap the library with your own module as shown by lhf

You cannot execute just a part of a Lua file. The file is loaded and exectuted as one chunk.

Alternatively just live with it. It doesn't harm you to have more functions available.

Comment: This leads to slow performance and unnecessary memory consumption. It takes more time to access to specific function.

Comment: @IgorK. that's no reason to downvote my correct answer. don't be so ungrateful. those functions end up in a table. it does not matter how many elements are in there. memory and performance issues with function definitions is neglectable on a PC.

Comment: @IgorK if performance matters you make the function local anyway so who cares about how many functions are loaded from a file